# Jetty/javalin getting HttpSession from websocket returns null always

Tags: java, jetty, javalin

Hello guys so am using javalin(uses jetty) and trying to get HttpSession but it returns null always! 
is there any better way i can get HttpSession in websockets without context?

```
    app.ws("/console",webSocketHandler -> {
           webSocketHandler.onConnect(wsSession -> {
               System.out.println(wsSession.getLocalAddress().getHostString() + " is Now Connected!");wsSession.send("ge");
           });
           webSocketHandler.onMessage((wsSession, s) -> {
               System.out.println((wsSession().getUpgradeRequest().getSession() == null)+"");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

`HttpSession` is an HTTP feature.

Once you are upgraded into WebSocket, you are no longer HTTP, hence no `HttpSession`.

If you want information from `HttpSession`, obtain the `HttpSession` during the upgrade process and then grab what you need from it.   Because once you are upgraded into WebSocket, that `HttpSession` is no longer valid for that request.

In Java you can do that with the Jetty `WebSocketCreator` or the JSR356 `Configurator`.